# Bootstrapping module specific styles/scripts in Zend Framework

Tags: php, javascript, css, zend-framework, module

I am trying to load specific styles/script resources for a specific module within my application.

Here is my application structure:

```
-application
  -configs
  -controllers
  -forms
  -layouts
  -models
  -modules
    -admin
      -configs
      -controllers
      -models
      -views
      -Bootstrap.php
  -views
  -Bootstrap.php
```

The problem I'm having is: the styles and scripts I am loading through `headLink()` and `headScript` in `/application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php` are also being loaded in my controller/actions that are *not* in the `admin` module. Here are my `Bootstrap.php`'s

*`/application/Bootstrap.php`*:

```
protected function _initDoctype()
{
    $this->_logger->info('Bootstrap ' . __METHOD__);

    //init the view
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');

    //Set title and separator
    $view->headTitle('Sunny Rose Photography')
         ->setSeparator(' | ');

    //Load global stylesheets
    $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/styles_main.css')
         ->headlink()->appendStylesheet('/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');

    //Load Scripts
    $view->headScript()->prependFile('/scripts/jquery-1.7.1/jquery-1.7.1.js')
         ->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js')
         ->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/gallery.js')
         ->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/scripts_main.js');
}
```

*`/application/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php`*:

```
 protected function _initDoctype()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/admin/styles_admin.css');
    $view->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/admin/scripts_admin.js');
}
```

I can see how or maybe why it's doing it: because I'm getting the view from the main bootsrap(?). My question is, how does one load module specific stylesheets and/or script files?

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, i searched for various wordings of the title of the question and I didn't find anything conclusive.

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not possible to determine name of module at bootstrap time . Only after routeShutdown you will come to know about module name . If you are using layout then open application.ini

```
resources.layout.pluginClass = "My_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout"
```

inside

```
class My_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout extends Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout
{

public function routeShutdown($request)
{
   $moduleName = $request->getModuleName();

if($moduleName == 'admin') 
{
// load css , js for this specific module
}
}
}
```

Comment: How would use go about using `headLink` etc like this since those need to be called on the `view`. i.e: `$this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('');
        $view->headScript()->appendFile('');`

Comment: $this->_layout->getView();  $this->_layout is instance of Zend_Layout  available from parent class

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it - I could just go to Zend/Layout/Controller/Plugin/Layout.php to see what methods it has. Thank you much.

Comment: i do not recommend extending layout plugin, rather create and register your own.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstraps for all modules being executed on every request.

I can suggest registering front controller plugin from bootstrap and do your conditional magic on preDispatch().

Comment: Thanks, I will figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a layout, an easier way is to add something like the following to the top of your layout page for a particular module:

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/admin/styles_admin.css');
$this->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/admin/scripts_admin.js');
```